# WCF binding configuration for SalesForce Api

Tags: wcf

For an application i'm developing i need to make a call on the SalesForce api. With SvcUtil i generated a proxy and integrated this in my solution. After i made a call via code, i get the following request and exception response. I use a normal basicHttpBinding.

```
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
  <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"></Action>
  <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink"></VsDebuggerCausalityData>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <username>XXX</username>
    <password>XXX</password>
  </login>
</s:Body>
```

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></s:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
    <faultcode xmlns="">soapenv:Client</faultcode>
    <faultstring xmlns="">No operation available for request {urn:partner.soap.sforce.com}login</faultstring>
  </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

However, if call the service with SoapUI, i don't get any errors. After googling i tried to make some changes in the binding and created a custom binding for forcing the soap version to 1.2, but didn't find a good solution. What should i change in the binding configuration?

This is the SoapUI call:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
<soapenv:Body>
  <urn:login>
     <urn:username>XXXX</urn:username>
     <urn:password>XXXX</urn:password>
  </urn:login>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research i found out that creating a proxy using "Add service reference" creates a proxy that works. So my problem is solved. Still have to check what the difference is between the generated proxies.